# Difficulties tuning an instrumental combo

Tags: tuning

There are three instruments involved:

1. A piano.
2. 2 guitars.
    One guitar is tuned to standard E A D G B E.
    The other guitar is tuned to an open D.
    The piano is standard tuning.

Why don't all 3 instruments sounds the same? The 2 guitars sounds the same, but when the piano comes in it is out of tune.

Comment: Did you tune the guitars to match the piano? Generally everyone has to tune to the piano because you can't retune a piano on the fly.

Comment: @ToddWilcox this is the answer

Answer (score 3):

This is an old problem, where the piano may well be in tune with itself, but not up to concert pitch - assuming it's an acoustic piano, in which case, it may not even be in tune with itself! There is no point in using guitar tuners for the guitars, so the reference point has to be the piano. Play the appropriate notes on the piano, and tune the guitars to those.

Before the days of electronic pianos, my band would use the oft available, oft slightly out of tune piano at the venue, and we all had to re-tune to that. Use the tuners to ascertain what the piano is tuned to as a matter of interest.